# Only start magnific popup when body has specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, magnific-popup

I am working with [magnific popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) and want to show a video when someone is coming to the side (including not showing it everytime a user comes to the site, hence the localStorage part). This all works and here is the code:

```
 (
    function($) {
        $(window).load(function () {
            if(localStorage.getItem('popState') != 'shown'){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $.magnificPopup.open({
                    items: {
                        src: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=blabla'
                    },
                    type: 'iframe',
                    iframe: {

                        patterns: {
                        youtube: {
                index: 'youtube.com/', 
                id: 'v=',
                src: 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/%id%?rel=0&autoplay=0'
            }
        }
    }
                });
            }, 5000);
            localStorage.setItem('popState','shown')}
        });
    })
(jQuery);
```

Now, I want to show the popup only on a specific page (when a specific language is selected). I noticed that the body tag changes the class when a user selects a language, example:

```
<body class="lang-en-EN">
```

or

```
<body class="lang-de-DE">
```

Is there a way to fire the popup, when the class changes from language EN to DE?

**Update: Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1cs93ed8/)**

Comment: That depends on what's changing the class, does the page reload or not ?

Comment: Check if the body has the class...

Comment: Yeah, like `if( $(body).hasClass("lang-en-EN") )`

Comment: See my updated fiddle, that does not work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the if-statement you already have, just check for the class as well, adding (e.g.) `$(body).hasClass("lang-en-DE")`:

```
(function($) {
    $(window).load(function () {
        if($(body).hasClass("lang-en-DE") && localStorage.getItem('popState') != 'shown'){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $.magnificPopup.open({
                items: {
                    src: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=blabla'
                },
                type: 'iframe',
                iframe: {
                    patterns: {
                        youtube: {
                            index: 'youtube.com/', 
                            id: 'v=',
                            src: 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/%id%?rel=0&autoplay=0'
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }, 5000);
        localStorage.setItem('popState','shown')}
    });
})
(jQuery);
```

Comment: I updated it with a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/1cs93ed8/), but the popup does not show up. I don't get any error either.

Comment: Well, you set up that jsfiddle to execute the JS code onLoad, but in the code itself you wait for $(window).load() again, which has already been fired and will therefore not fire again. Change it to "No wrap - in head" and clear your localStorage, then it will work: http://jsfiddle.net/1cs93ed8/1/ - and of course it should work in an ordinary page bound to the load event.

Comment: To make it even clearer, here's another update with a timeout of 0 and the localStorage check commented out, which shows the popup every time if the class is set: http://jsfiddle.net/1cs93ed8/2/